# Perceptron algorithm in R, the process is stuck at the 1st epoch

Tags: r, algorithm, perceptron

I have been trying to make my own perceptron algorithm. But, it seems as if the algorithm stops at the first epoch, and as a result there is not correct classification.
The following is my implementation of the perceptron algorithm in R.

```
x1 <- runif(30,-1,1) 
x2 <- runif(30,-1,1) 
x <- cbind(x1,x2) 
w = matrix(0,3,1)  # initialize weights for x1, x2, bias
b <- c(0,0)          # bias = 0
xb<- cbind(x,b)      # importing bias (x1,x2,b) 
y <- ifelse(x2>0.5+x1,+1,-1) #y target

perceptron = function(xb,y,w, learning.rate=0.5){
  k = 1000           # count epochs
  error <- matrix(, nrow = nrow(xb), ncol = k, byrow = TRUE)
  #xb[,3] is the col of biases

  for (j in 1:k) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
      yc <- sum(xb[i,] * w) #ycomputed
      error[i,k] <- y[i] - yc
      if (y[i] != yc) {
        w <- w + learning.rate * error[i,k] * x[i,] 
        xb[i,3] <- xb[i,3] + learning.rate * error[i,k]      #b <- b + learning.rate * (y[i]-yc) 
      }
      else {
        w <- w
        xb[i,3] <- xb[i,3]
      }
    }
    return(list(w,xb[,3],error[,k]))
    if (w[k] == w[k-1]){
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Also ,there seems to be a computational fault on my side starting at:

> w <- w + learning.rate * error[i,k] * x[i,]

For the above, this comment appears on the console:"Error in cat("1: In w + learning.rate * error * x[i, ] :\n  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length",  : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
In addition: There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"
. I can not make sense out of this ,because to my eyes there does not seem to be a problem, as it is a vector(w) multiplied by a number(learning.rate * error * x[i, ]).
Thank you for your time reading and hopefully answering my question.